# Using of not captured variable in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, standards, c++14

I can not quite understand an example from C++14 standard draft `N4140 5.1.2.12 [expr.prim.lambda]`.

> A lambda-expression with an associated capture-default that does not explicitly capture this or a variable with automatic storage duration (this excludes any id-expression that has been found to refer to an initcapture’s associated non-static data member), is said to implicitly capture the entity (i.e., this or a variable) if the compound-statement:
>
> - odr-uses the entity, or
> - names the entity in a potentially-evaluated expression where the enclosing full-expression depends on a generic lambda parameter declared within the reaching scope of the lambda-expression.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {}) { } // #1
> void f(const int&, const int (&)[1]) { } // #2
> void test() {
>   const int x = 17;
>   auto g = [](auto a) {
>     f(x); // OK: calls #1, does not capture x
>   };
>   auto g2 = [=](auto a) {
>     int selector[sizeof(a) == 1 ? 1 : 2]{};
>     f(x, selector); // OK: is a dependent expression, so captures x
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]
>
> All such implicitly captured entities shall be declared within the reaching scope of the lambda expression.
>
> [ Note: The implicit capture of an entity by a nested lambda-expression can cause its implicit capture by the containing lambda-expression (see below). Implicit odr-uses of this can result in implicit capture. —end note ]

I thought that the beginning of a phrase `a lambda-expression with an associated capture-default` should prohibit any implicit capture (and it's confirmed by comment), therefore `#1` call will lead to an error (something about using not captured variable). So how it works? What will be first argument of `f`? What if `g` will be called after exiting `test()` scope? What if I change `#1` signature to `void(const int&)`?

--

upd: Thanks to all for explanation of how it works. Later I'll try to find and post references to standard about this case.

Comment: `x` is a const expression. which is ODR-used only for #2 because of the reference.

Comment: In other words, `g` behaves as if its body is `{ f(17); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As T.C. said in his comment, #1 does not require a capture as `x` is known at compile time and is therefore baked into the lambda. Not unlike how the function `f` is known at compile time so it doesn't need to be captured.

I believe if you change `f`'s signature to `int const &` you are now attempting to pass the address of the constant which is on the stack, thus subject to changes, and it would require capturing `x` by value or reference.